# Split DataGridView into two columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

In my Winforms application I have a DataGridView. I know that this grid will always have 12 rows. But grid with 12 rows is too high for my application and I don't want to enable scrolling.

What I want to know is if I can split the DGV into two "columns". I mean that I have a grid with 6 rows and next to it I have next grid with next 6 rows. I don't want to create two DGVs because there is only one datasource and it would be complicated to decide which rows shoud be shown in which DGV. Here is what I want to achieve with one DGV:

[image: Example]
Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want complicated solutions/workaround then design not complicated layout for your data....

Comment: I know. I just want to know if it is even possible. Of course I have some other solutions (different layout). But this would be perfect for my case... If it is not possible, I will make it in different way

Comment: You can do it n different ways - but afraid without "complicated" workarounds you cannot do it with one datagridview...

Comment: That is what I want to hear. I thought that I can't do it with one DGV but I wanted to ask... Thanks

Comment: @DanielH - This kind of split is supported in thrid party DataGrids like [TruDBGrid](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/TrueDBGridWinForms/)... just want to give other possibilties but this is no endorsement :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating 2 gridviews and bind the first to the first 6 records and the second to the remaining six records.

Comment: I don't want to use this solution because everything goes to be complicated with that (for example sorting - I can sort one DGW but not two DGVs together).

Comment: I hope you find an answer... I'd be quite interested if you do find one. You could of course page the grid... it would mean that you would only see 6 records at a time but sorting etc. would be possible.

Comment: If I had to do it I would create the layout in codebehind. No Gridview. Data into data table. Then parse through data and display as you require. You would of course need to add your own code to sort etc.